# How to get the directory path of a script in the shebang line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, shebang

Currently I can run a script only from the containing directory since the shebang line includes a path relative to the current directory

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift -F ./Rome/ -framework Swiftline
```

How is it possible to modify the `"."` to an absolute path?

`./Rome/` to something that will work from any directory? I've tried the following:

`$0/Rome/` doesn't work

`dirname $0` /Rome/ doesn't work

`$1/Rome/` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift -F ./Rome/ -framework Swiftline` won't work because of the way the shebang line works. Everything after the first space on the shebang line is taken as a single argument. In this case, env will be passed "xcrun swift -F ./Rome/ -framework Swiftline" as first argument and the filename containing this shebang as second argument, which will not work since `xcrun swift -F ./Rome/ -framework Swiftline` is not a file.

You can see that easily by making a fake interpreter which just prints its arguments, for example a `/tmp/run.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

Then using this interpreter in a script `/tmp/foo.sh`:

```
#!/tmp/run.sh -a -b -c
exit
```

When running foo.sh, you will see arguments passed to the interpreter:

```
-a -b -c
./foo.sh
```

You will have to provide a normal shell script that runs the `xcrun` stuff in addition to your file. The shebang will not work for your case.

Comment: create a regular `run.sh` which just launches `xcrun swift -F etc.`, the shebang is not powerful enough for your use

Comment: yea. resorted to adding a wrapper. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this when PyCharm created a virtual environment `venv` in the project folder with spaces in the full path. For such case, there are a simple workaround - I moved the project into the space-free location and recreated the `venv` there. All files in the shebang path now contain an absolute path to the new location and everything works.

To finish the workaround, I created a symlink back to the original location of the project's folder. Now I have an operational `pip`, etc there.

Not the finest solution, but I can work in the original place the way I need, keeping the aux crap in one place :-). Of course, it is the pure Pythonic issue and workaround as well.